# QTreeWidgetItem Change - Detect Enter/ESC

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm developing a Qt/C++ app with a *QTreeWidgetItem*. When a new item is created I set it `setEditable` and it allow me to fill directly in the UI the new name.

I'm currently using `itemChanged` as shown below to catch the change and save it. By default, I set the new item name to new folder and after I can change it manually. My issue is when I'm creating the item, it becomes editable and if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> without any changes, the `itemChanged` is not generated.

Is there a command I can use based on SIGNAL/SLOT which can catch the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> event. The goal is to triggered the same signals

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
        this, SLOT(onTreeItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*)));
```

I want to connect <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Esc</kbd> signals to `onTreeItemChanged` as it's done for `itemChanged`.

I have tried the use of `itemActivated`, but it's not triggered even if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(itemActivated(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
        this, SLOT(onTreeItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*)));
```

Any idea,

Seb

Comment: [This question looks like it may solve your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538057/catch-esc-key-press-event-when-editing-a-qtreewidgetitem)

Comment: nop this is why I have added that the event is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to write this in answer, but i still cant comment:

I had some (maybe) similar problems concerning a class derived from QCombobox, which had some spetial behaviour, when to show the popup and when not to.

Everytime Return was pressed domething happend but it wasent a **QEventKeyEvent**, the solution was to catch **QEvent::Shortcut**, because the element interpreted this key as shortcut for accept.

-- EDIT --
In such cases i often install a event fiolter and let it just write the events to the output, using a switch statement to filter out uninteresting elements, till i get the culprit.

Comment: I was able to see the QEventKeyEvent.

Comment: I dont see a easy solution for tha one, 
Maybe you could use the **currentIndex ()** (inherited from QAbstractItemView) to get the item index and use it in a custom signal when the **QAbstractItemDelegate *  itemDelegate ()** fires a **closeEditor**?

This is a guess but the delegate schould fire this signal when the editor closes (no matter if it is Return/escape or clicking somewhere else, maybe you want to use a filter on the delegate to only get the key). The currentItem schould return the Item that had the editor open, and you could implement a signal my_itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*).

Comment: When the item is created with the coorect name (without changing) edited wont fire, (you might get a item added but i supose you only want to act after the editor-delegate has ben closed.)

Comment: yes you are right but I can manage to change the itemChanged to an editor closed in that case it will be the same for me

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to subclass Keyevent but issue is that the event is generated before the new value entered is treated by QTreeWIdgetItem. In that case I catch the event but too early