# QTreeWidgetItem editable allow entering number only

Tags: c++, qt

I created a **QTreeWidget** with several **QTreeWidgetItem**.

Here is my code:

```
//Defined property tree
m_pPropertyTree = new QTreeWidget();
m_pPropertyTree->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
m_pPropertyTree->setColumnCount(2);
m_pPropertyTree->setHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Property" << "Value");
//Update to property tree
//--geometry
QTreeWidgetItem *pGeometryItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(m_pPropertyTree);
pGeometryItem->setText(0, "geometry");
//X
QTreeWidgetItem *pXItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pXItem->setText(0, "X");
pXItem->setText(1, QString::number(geometry().x()));
pXItem->setFlags(pXItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
pGeometryItem->addChild(pXItem);
//Y
QTreeWidgetItem *pYItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pYItem->setText(0, "Y");
pYItem->setText(1, QString::number(geometry().y()));
pYItem->setFlags(pYItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
pGeometryItem->addChild(pYItem);
//Width
QTreeWidgetItem *pWidthItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pWidthItem->setText(0, "Width");
pWidthItem->setText(1, QString::number(geometry().width()));
pWidthItem->setFlags(pWidthItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
pGeometryItem->addChild(pWidthItem);
//Height
QTreeWidgetItem *pHeightItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
pHeightItem->setText(0, "Height");
pHeightItem->setText(1, QString::number(geometry().height()));
pHeightItem->setFlags(pHeightItem->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
pGeometryItem->addChild(pHeightItem);
```

When double clicked on an item, i can edit that item's text. However, i want to only allow user to enter number when editing. Is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a number of methods, but overloading of [QItemDelegate::createEditor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#createEditor) is a more useful than others.

You should write code with `QValidator`, in your case, use `QIntValidator`.

```
class CustomDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option,
                      const QModelIndex & index) const
    {
        QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);

        // Set your validator, such as 'only number between 0 ~ 9 )
        QIntValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(0, 9, lineEdit);
        lineEdit->setValidator(validator);

        return lineEdit;
    }
};
```

And then, set your custom delegate to your tree.

```
m_pPropertyTree->setItemDelegate( new CustomDelegate );
```

Comment: It work, that's great, but i need to ask you something. Is there any way to implement this without create a new class ?. Moreover, this will apply to entire tree, how about if i want to apply to a few items in TreeWidget.

Comment: If you want to apply to a few items, overloading of `createEditor` is not a proper way. You will find a other method for this, in [this article.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538057/catch-esc-key-press-event-when-editing-a-qtreewidgetitem)

Comment: The createEditor method has the index parameter, from wich you can get the row, the column and the model data of the cell. You can create the right editor for each cell.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I don't quite understand how QItemDelegate works

Comment: Is there anyway to setItemDelegate( new CustomDelegate ); and then unset it ?